# Mount external files into Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have a prediction application with the below folder structure:

```
Docker
├── dataset
│   └── fastText
│       └── crawl-300d-2M.vec
├── Dockerfile
├── encoder
│   └── sentencoder2.pkl
├── pyt_models
│   └── actit1.pt
├── requirements.txt
└── src
    ├── action_items_api.py
    ├── infer_predict.py
    ├── model.py
    ├── models.py
    └── sent_enc.py
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

EXPOSE 80


# copy and install packages for flask

COPY /requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN cd /tmp && \
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt


WORKDIR /Docker

COPY src src

CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 --chdir src action_items_api:app
```

In the Docker file I try only to copy the src folder where all the Python files are placed. I want to keep the fastTest, ecnode, pyt_models to be accessed outside the container.

When I tried:

```
docker run -p8080:80 -v /encoder/:/encoder/;/pyt_models/:/pyt_models/;/dataset/:/dataset/ -it actit_mount:latest
```

But by doing this my code gives me `FileNotFoundError` `No such file or directory: 'encoder/sentencoder2.pkl'`

But by keeping the same folder structure if I run from the docker folder:
`gunicorn --chdir src --bind 0.0.0.0:80 action_items_api:app` It works.

What is wrong with the Dockerfile or the `docker run`?

Comment: The run command is definitely wrong. For a corrections we need to know on which OS you are trying this.

Comment: @Henry Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you set `WORKDIR /Docker`, the gunicorn process will have its working directory set to `/Docker`. Which implies that relative file paths in your python app will be resolved from `/Docker`.

Give a try to

```sh
docker run -p8080:80 \ 
  -v $(pwd)/encoder/:/Docker/encoder/ \
  -v $(pwd)/pyt_models/:/Docker/pyt_models/ \
  -v $(pwd)/dataset/:/Docker/dataset/ \
  -it actit_mount:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

docker: Error response from daemon: create ./folder: "./folder" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

Here is an example:

[image: example of docker run -v]